# Using Wget to download an entire website with images

Tags: linux, wget

I am able to download a complete website except images with the following command:

```
wget -mk -r --html-extension --no-clobber --continue --mirror --adjust-extension --convert-links --no-cookies mainDomain.com
```

However, when I try to download images which are hosted on a different domain using the command below, only the `index.html` is downloaded.

```
wget -mk -r --html-extension --no-clobber --continue --mirror --adjust-extension --convert-links --no-cookies -H -Dimage-Domain.com, mainDomain.com
```

What is the problem?

Comment: What message do you get when you try to download one of the images (with adequate `--referer` if necessary)? Some sites also check the user-agent and won't serve requests is the UA isn't a known browser (IE/Edge/Firefox/Chrome/Opera)(but `wget` will let you fake that).

Comment: I get this message 'Reusing existing connection to imageDomain.com:443.'

Comment: So, no error message, but whatever the URL used on imageDomain.com, you only get the root `index.html`? Looks typical of a site that checks the user-agent and http-referer strings. Or you have to dig the JS of the initial website page. Is it making calls to imageDomain? Your browser can help you find this ("network debug" function...)

Comment: Yes, no errors, and without '-D' command all fine but no images.. however, I tried everything except 'http-referer strings' what is the command? here is the website where images hosted modo3*com

Comment: `--http-referer` and `--user-agent` lets you set arbitrary headers in the WGET requests. `modo3.com` just returns an XML?

Comment: `--http-referer` (no such command) I tried `--referer= https://modo3*com --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" https://mainDomain.com` correct? `modo3*com`  return `index.html`

Comment: No matter what I try with wget it always return index.html for `modo3*com`